# How to create new array with same reversed items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have to exclude duplicate elements from array like this:

```
0: (2) ["10 * 1", "15 * 2"]
1: (2) ["25 * 1", "15 * 1"]
2: (2) ["15 * 1", "25 * 1"]
3: (2) ["15 * 2", "10 * 1"]
```

arr[0] equals arr[3] and arr[1] equals arr[2], so only unique should remain.

I started to make comparsion algorythm with sth like this

```
let resultCopy = result.slice();
let sortedRes = resultCopy.map((item) => {
    return item.reverse();
});
```

But even though map() should return new array, and even though I created a copy, the original array is being changed with reversed items.

Why am I getting such behaviour? Maybe there is better way to exclude duplicates?

Comment: Will the inner arrays always have two elements?

Comment: @RameshReddy it will, but I try to avoid hardcoding

Comment: Where exactly in your code you remove the inverse/duplicate entries?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan algorythm is not completed, I'm stuck exactly at this part

Comment: @CaelumVallis why you care you mutate it?

Comment: Note you actually have two question. 1. How to deepclone an array. 2. how to reverse an array.

Comment: @appleapple because I have to compare them in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Map returns a new Array, `result` has reference type(`item`) and `reverse` will mutate the array. You're directly mutating the `reference`s, that's why original items being changed, Create a copy and traverse them. Like below

```js
const result = [
   ["10 * 1", "15 * 2"],
   ["25 * 1", "15 * 1"],
   ["15 * 1", "25 * 1"],
   ["15 * 2", "10 * 1"]
]

const resultReverse = result.map(item => [...item].reverse())

const sortReversedList = resultReverse.map(item => [...item].sort()) // will have sorted items

const hashMap = {} // to handles dupes
for (const item of sortReversedList) {
  const key = item.toString();
  if (!hashMap[key]) {
    hashMap[key] = item // store uniques items
  }
}

const uniques = Object.values(hashMap);

// console.log(resultReverse); // will have dupes, need to write code to handle dupes
// console.log(result); // won't change the original array
console.log(uniques);
```

Comment: Have you read the first paragraph of the quesiton?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan he solved my problem with reversing, I'll try to complete algorythm by myself

Comment: Problem is here `item.reverse()`, it will change the original array values, because its `reference` type

Comment: @Naren I would not say so - the duplicated entries are still there, even so, per your question statement `[a, b], [a, b]` are also duplicate entries, in the same order - but still duplicates.

Comment: @CaelumVallis updated the unique elements as well, lemme know if this helpful!!

Comment: Cool, Glad it was helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the inner arrays and get a JSON for comparing with a `Set`.

```js
const
    getValue = ([...array]) => JSON.stringify(array.sort()),
    array = [["10 * 1", "15 * 2"], ["25 * 1", "15 * 1"], ["15 * 1", "25 * 1"], ["15 * 2", "10 * 1"]],
    result = array
        .filter((s => v => (w => !s.has(w) && s.add(w))(getValue(v)))(new Set))
        .reverse();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but maybe there is some simpler method

Comment: @CaelumVallis, does it return the wanted result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set to keep track of the joined arrays in actual and reversed orders.

```js
const input = [
  ['10 * 1', '15 * 2'],
  ['10 * 1', '15 * 2'],
  ['25 * 1', '15 * 1'],
  ['15 * 1', '25 * 1'],
  ['15 * 2', '10 * 1'],
  ['15 * 2', '10 * 1'],
];

const uniquePairs = new Set();

const result = input.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const joined = el.join();
  const reverseJoined = [...el].reverse().join();
  if (!uniquePairs.has(reverseJoined) && !uniquePairs.has(joined)) {
    acc.push(el);
  }
  uniquePairs.add(joined, reverseJoined);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```